# format a nullable DateTime? inside a query with other columns

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a WebMethod that returns all the columns for a certain ProjectID which works great. But when I return the column StartDate, which is a DateTime?, I get the following returned: /Date(1391068800000)/.

Here's the WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public static object getProjectByID(int id)
{
    using (dbPSREntities7 myEntities = new dbPSREntities7())
    {
        var thisProject = myEntities.tbProjects.Where(x => x.ProjectID == id);

        var columns = thisProject.Select(x => new { x.ProjectContactFirstName, x.ProjectContactLastName, x.refDepartmentID, x.refAuthSignerID, x.ProjectAccountNum, x.ProjectContactInfo, x.refBuildingID, x.ProjectRoomNum, x.ProjectWorkType, x.ProjectDescription, x.ProjectManagerID, x.MaintenanceAccount, x.StartDate }).ToList();

        // I basically want to format x.StartDate correctly
        // and keep it part of the return statement.

        return columns;
    }
}
```

I've been able to overcome this before when I was selecting ONLY one date from a table, but not one date with a bunch of other columns. Here's the code where I return only one DateTime? column which works:

```
[WebMethod]
public static object getBreadCrumbDate(int projectID, int statusID)
{
    using (dbPSREntities7 myEntities = new dbPSREntities7())
    {
        var thisId = myEntities.tbBreadCrumbs.Where(x => x.ProjectID == projectID && x.StatusID == statusID).Max(x => x.BreadCrumbID);
        var columns = myEntities.tbBreadCrumbs
            .Where(x => x.BreadCrumbID == thisId)
            .Select(x => x.CreateDateTime)
            .ToList();

        if (columns.Any())
        {
            var formattedList = columns
                .Select(d => null != d
                    ? d.Value.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy")
                    : string.Empty) // this is just one example to handle null
                .ToList();

            return formattedList;
        }
        else
        {
            return "In Progress";
        }

    }
}
```

How would I incorporate the bottom code into the top code so that StartDate is returned as part of the recordset but have the date formatted as "MMM dd yyyy"?

Answer (score 0):

In your first method:

```
... x.MaintenanceAccount, x.StartDate, FormattedDate = (x.StartDate.HasValue ? x.StartDate.Value.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy") : String.Empty) }).ToList();
```

Although I personally think that formatting belongs solely a responsibility of the presentation.  I don't think your entity should carry a formatted representation of a Date value.

Comment: I got the Application Error:  "No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments" so I added ".Value" to: ? x.StartDate.Value.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy")

I no longer get an Application Error, but now I get error from AJAX: "The cast to value type \u0027Int32\u0027 failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type\u0027s generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type."